# Python dictionary new index returns NaN value

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and just started learning Pandas.

I created a dictionary and want to change the index.

However, the new index shows NaN for all the values which I expect 3,5,8,-2 respectively.

I attached my code here for your reference:

```
states = ['place1','place2','place3','place4']

sdata = dict(a=3,b=5,c=8,d=-2)

obj4 = pd.Series(sdata, index=states)
print(obj4)

place1   NaN
place2   NaN
place3   NaN
place4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your goal?

Comment: I am just trying to change the original index which is a,b,c,d to something new such as states. However with index changed the value becomes NaN as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

When you create series with a dictionary, the keys are taken as index and values are, well, values. So,

```
pd.Series(sdata)
```

would give you:

```
a    3
b    5
c    8
d   -2
dtype: int64
```

Now, if in addition, you pass `index` to `pd.Series(some_dict)` it is equivalent to a `reindex`:

```
pd.Series(sdata).reindex(states)
```

and since `states` doesn't contains any keys in `sdata`, you get a series indexed by `states` and contains all `NaN`.

If you are certain about the order, you can create the series with:

```
pd.Series(list(sdata.values()), index=states)
```

Output:

```
place1    3
place2    5
place3    8
place4   -2
dtype: int64
```